# CryptQueryObject / CryptDecryptMessage extremely slow for large files/blobs

Tags: delphi, winapi, encryption, cryptography, cng

I am trying to decrypt a p7m attachment using `CryptQueryObject` / `CryptDecryptMessage` functions. For large files (30Mb) each call can take up to 30 seconds to execute. Outlook itself has no problem opening an encrypted message and showing its contents instantaneously.

I do realize `CryptQueryObject` is deprecated (but `CryptDecryptMessage` is not). It does not matter what parameters I use and whether the data is in a memory blob or a file. Below is the Delphi code (C++ would be very similar). If I pause the execution while either function is executing, I can see from the call stack that the code is resizing or allocating a new memory block. It is almost as if the code is building a buffer reallocating/copying the previous contents on each iteration.

Here is what the call looks like, nothing extraordinary, no amount of playing with the parameters makes the calls any faster.

```
if not CryptQueryObject(CERT_QUERY_OBJECT_FILE,//CERT_QUERY_OBJECT_BLOB,
                        pointer(PWideChar(wFileName)),//@stCryptBlob,
                        CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_PKCS7_UNSIGNED or CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_PKCS7_SIGNED, //CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_ALL, //CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_PKCS7_SIGNED_EMBED,
                        CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_ALL, //CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_BINARY,
                        0,
                        nil, //@dwEncoding,    // X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING
                        @dwContentType, // a PKCS7 signed message embedded in a file    CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_PKCS7_SIGNED_EMBED = 10
                        nil, //@dwFormatType,  // the content is in binary format CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_BINARY = 1
                        @hStore,
                        nil, //@hMsg, // for dwContentType == CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_PKCS7_SIGNED,
                                      //        CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_PKCS7_UNSIGNED
                                      //        CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_PKCS7_SIGNED_EMBED
                        nil {@pvContext}) then RaiseLastWindowError('CryptQueryObject');
```

And here is the typical call stack when the function is executing. It is always memory/heap related.

```
:77dc8913 ntdll.memcpy + 0x33
:77d93526 ; 
:77d92867 ; 
:77d92763 ntdll.RtlReAllocateHeap + 0x43
:75d3a1f5 ; C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\KERNELBASE.dll
:754a869c MSASN1.ASN1EncSetError + 0x5c
:754a5bf9 ; C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\MSASN1.dll
:754a1b67 MSASN1.ASN1BERDecOctetString + 0x17
:769b485f ; C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\CRYPT32.dll
:769b42e5 ; C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\CRYPT32.dll
:754a2e3c ; C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\MSASN1.dll
:7690a697 ; C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\CRYPT32.dll
:769b3354 ; C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\CRYPT32.dll
:7694053a ; C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\CRYPT32.dll
:7692d71b ; C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\CRYPT32.dll
:7692d373 ; C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\CRYPT32.dll
uEncryptedMessage.DecodeP7M($356A3C50)
```

Anybody knows why this happens? 
Did anybody have luck processing large encrypted blobs using these functions?
Would I be better off using the new CNG functions? What would the sequence of calls be like then?

Comment: There is no question!

Comment: The question is how to make it faster?

Comment: "_30Mb_" strictly means `M` = [mega](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mega-) (1 * 1000 * 1000) and `b` = **bit** ([see Megabit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabit)) - that'd be 3,750,000 **byte**. Whereas `Mi` = [mebi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix#IEC_prefixes) (1 * 1024 * 1024) and `B` = **byte**. Did you mean `30 MiB` instead of `3.75 kB`?

Comment: Have you tried pre-allocating a buffer/buffers so they don't have to be reallocated? Maybe just making the buffers larger would help?

Comment: Cryptographic calculations are optimized for input-invariant execution times. This is generally orthogonal to raw performance. Whether you can get better performance with the CNG API is something you would need to  evaluate.

Comment: @rossum - `CryptQueryObject` does not use an output buffer, it exists solely to extract various properties of the input blob and IMHO should not even try to decrypt the buffer: surely it does not need to decrypt the whole thing to figure out the type of encryption? For `CryptDecryptMessage`, I run it twice: once with a (0, null) output buffer to return the size of the output data, and the second time with an allocated buffer of the required length. It takes just as long in both cases. I can of course over-allocate the buffer and call it only once, but that will shave off about 30% of the time.

Comment: @IInspectable - I would love to use CNG, and that would be one of my questions: what are the CNG functions I need to use? I could not find any code sample that does something similar to what I do with `CryptQueryObject` / `CryptDecryptMessage`.

Comment: You know the size of the blob? Can't you use that to guess the output size?

Comment: @Anders - I can, but that would be a 1/3 reduction at best: `CryptQueryObject` does not use an output buffer, `CryptDecryptMessage` is called twice (once to find the size of the buffer and second time to actually decrypt), so I can get rid of the first call to `CryptDecryptMessage` - 60 seconds instead of 90 would be better, but still not acceptable.